# Delete Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api, swift4

How to delete specific google calendar event from my app?
 Here is code I have to fetch google calendar events. 
    I am displaying all events on table view if I tapped on table view cell menu appears with delete option when I tap delete then selected event should be deleted.

```
    func fetchEvents() {
        let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.query(withCalendarId: "primary")
        query.maxResults = 10
        query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date())
        query.singleEvents = true
        query.orderBy = kGTLRCalendarOrderByStartTime
        service.executeQuery(
            query,
            delegate: self,
            didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
    }
```

Display the start dates and event summaries in the UITextView

```
    @objc func displayResultWithTicket(
        ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
        finishedWithObject response : GTLRCalendar_Events,
        error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var outputText = ""
        if let events = response.items, !events.isEmpty {
            for event in events {
                let start = event.start!.dateTime ?? event.start!.date!
                let startString = DateFormatter.localizedString(
                    from: start.date,
                    dateStyle: .short,
                    timeStyle: .short)
                eventDateArray.add(start.date)


                let dataDic = ["fullTimeAndDate":startString , "tag":"red", "eventType":event.summary!] // MonthDataModel(fullTimeAndDate: seprated[1], tag: "red", appointmentType: event.eTag)
                eventArray.add(dataDic)

                outputText += "\(startString) - \(event.summary!)\n"
                print("Output ", startString , event )
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(eventDateArray, forKey: "EventDataArray")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: eventArray), forKey: "EventArray")


            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        } else
        {
            outputText = "No upcoming events found."
        }
        print("Output Text",outputText)
        showAlert(title: "Event Sync Succesfully!", message:"")
    }
```

Please guide me I am new with swift and stack overflow too.

I am trying this code to delete calendar event but no luck.

```
  func deleteGoogleCalendarEvent() {

        let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsDelete.query(withCalendarId: "primary", eventId: self.del_Event_id)

        service.executeQuery(query, GTLRServiceCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoo!! I got it. Just need to do some changes in delete function call and some work on selector function of delete function

```
   func deleteGoogleCalendarEvent() {

        let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsDelete.query(withCalendarId: "primary", eventId: self.del_Event_id)

        service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(deleteResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedDelete:error:)))
    }
```

Here is selector (deleteResultWithTicket)

```
@objc func deleteResultWithTicket(
        ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
        finishedDelete response: GTLRCalendarQuery_AclDelete,
        error : NSError?) {

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription!)
            return
        }
        self.fetchGoogleCalendarEvents()
    }
```

Make Sure about scopes if you want to do write operation on google calendar event you must set scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeCalendar].

Comment: Which SDK/POD you are using ? I don't see any proper documentation.

Comment: GoogleAPIClientForREST pod used. @JamshedAlam

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using [Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) to perform this where you need to provide `calendarId` and `eventId`. For the code implementation in Swift, follow this guide:

[Swift Google Calendar: Delete an Event](http://rest-examples.chilkat.io/google_calendar/swift/chilkat_46.cshtml)

```
func chilkatTest() {
    let rest = CkoRest()
    var success: Bool

    //   Provide a previously obtained OAuth2 access token.
    let oauth2 = CkoOAuth2()
    oauth2.AccessToken = "OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    rest.SetAuthOAuth2(oauth2)

    success = rest.Connect("www.googleapis.com", port: 443, tls: true, autoReconnect: true)
    if success != true {
        print("\(rest.LastErrorText)")
        return
    }

    let sbResponse = CkoStringBuilder()
    success = rest.FullRequestNoBodySb("DELETE", uriPath: "/calendar/v3/calendars/support@chilkatcloud.com/events/1p7fb5vob7vm57fepk4p1teft9", sb: sbResponse)
    if success != true {
        print("\(rest.LastErrorText)")
        return
    }

    if rest.ResponseStatusCode.integerValue != 204 {
        print("Received error response code: \(rest.ResponseStatusCode.integerValue)")
        print("Response body:")
        print("\(sbResponse.GetAsString())")
        return
    }

    print("Example Completed.")

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I got a solution.

Comment: post your solution.

Comment: If possible can you pose code, how you fetching the events from google calendar, I am facing the issue while fetching. @tdakus

Comment: @tdakus waiting for your reply here

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper have you post your question

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper I can't post answer here.

Comment: can you answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298936/getting-nserror-domain-com-google-gtljsonrpcerrordomain-while-fetching-google

Comment: @tdakus pls check above query