# Deleting a Google calendar event deletes it from the iPhone's calendar, but not from the MacBook's one

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekevent, ekeventstore

I receive events in this way:

```
let store = EKEventStore()
let predicate = store.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, calendars: nil)
let events = store.events(matching: predicate)
```

And remove one of them in this way:

```
try store.remove(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
```

It removes event from iPhone's calendar, but does not from MacBook's. The event came from Google calendar. If I do these things with an event came from iCloud calendar, it works both on iPhone and MacBook. I have tried different ways to solve this problem but without success. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51244310/341994

Comment: Hm, looks interesting, thanks! But what confuses me is that I was able to remove the Google event without being bound to the Google API. And this seems to be normal behavior because it's an iOS calendar managed by my AppleID. I expect the same behavior from the macbook calendar app, but no, it doesn't work. It's strange. I guess deleting an event from a Google calendar and deleting a Google event from a macOS calendar are slightly different mechanisms. But anyway I'll try it.

Comment: "I guess deleting an event from a Google calendar and deleting a Google event from a macOS calendar are slightly different mechanisms" Very different; that's the point. The iOS calendar API is managing your iCloud (and local) calendars; it is merely _subscribing_ to the Google calendars. You can check what abilities you have from EventKit by querying the Google calendar's `isImmutable` and `allowsContentModifications` properties.

Comment: However, I'm always confused by how these subscriptions work; perhaps your iOS device and your Mac are subscribed to the Google calendar in different ways, or they do not sync up automatically, or something.